# PAM unable to dlopen(pan_systemd.so) when to login on tty1

Tags: login, pam

Every time I login in my OS with x-window, that is in tty7.
When I change from tty7 into tty1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I can't login with right account name and right password.

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
Aug 30 10:31:15 hwy login[576]: PAM unable to dlopen(pan_systemd.so): /lib/security/pan_systemd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Aug 30 10:31:15 hwy login[576]: PAM adding faulty module: pan_systemd.so
Aug 30 10:31:17 hwy login[2369]: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
Aug 30 10:31:17 hwy login[576]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
Aug 30 10:31:17 hwy systemd-logind[487]: New session 5 of user root.
Aug 30 10:31:17 hwy systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 30 10:31:17 hwy login[576]: Module is unknown
Aug 30 10:31:18 hwy systemd-logind[487]: Removed session 5.
```

There is no `/lib/security/pan_systemd.so` here.

```
ls /lib/security/
pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

My desktop is lxde not gnome,why pam_gnome_keyring.so is here,can i delete it safely?
I found a way to solce it at the same time to import a new problem here.

```
vim /etc/pam.d/login
#session required pan_systemd.so

(to change `session required pan_systemd.so` into `#session required pan_systemd.so` , or say to comment `session required pan_systemd.so`)
```

Now to change from tty7 into tty1 , i can login with account name and password.
However a new problem has arisen，there is an error info when to reboot.

[image]
Ｉam in a dilemma.
How to solve the two problems simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

pam_systemd.so is provided by libpam-systemd. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpam-systemd
```